# Python loop for to examine XML file

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to print the result of a for loop using the value defined by the user. for example, if the user enters the number 9 as an identifiant (id_donne), the program has to search inside the xml file and search the id_guy tag and get me out the first and last name of this person.

Here is an example of what's inside the xml file

```
<record><id_guy>1</id_guy><first_name>Homere</first_name><last_name>Latham</last_name></record>
```

```
xml_file = minidom.parse('id_guyy.xml')
id_guys = xml_file.getElementsByTagName('id_guy')

id_donne = int(input ("Please enter the person ID (maximum: 1000) > "))

for d in id_guys :
            if int(d.attributes['id_guy'].value) == id_donne :
                print('first name: ' + d.attributes['first_name'].value)
                print('last name: ' + d.attributes['last_name'].value)
                print('-------')
```

but this gives me an **error**:

```
if d.attributes['id_guy'].value == id_donne :
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 555, in __getitem__
 
return self._attrs[attname_or_tuple]

KeyError: 'id_guy'
```

Comment: Be aware of the difference between attributes and children in XML. Your XML does not have attributes, however, your code searches for those. Another thing I see is wrong that you run `getElementsByTagName` with argument `id_guy`, while you should probably run it with `record`.

Comment: Do you have to use minidom or can you use elementtree or lxml?

Comment: would it be possible to show a slightly larger example with 3 or more records ?
I would like to confirm the structure of the xml.